# iOS - Set Derived Property

Tags: ios, objective-c, properties, getter-setter

I have the following derived property:

`SongWrapper.h`

`@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *title;`

`SongWrapper.m`

```
- (NSString *)title;
{
    return self.songDocument.songAttributes.title;
}
```

I tried to set it like this:

`self.songViewController.songWrapper.title = titleTextField.text;`

Why doesn't this work and what are the best practices for setting a derived property?

Comment: You mean in the setter (setTitle) you can't do that? What error do you get? By the looks of it, this is not a derived property? Just some method of another property?

Comment: When I try to `setTitle:` then access `.title` again, the title isn't changed.

Btw, I can override `setTitle:` to `self.songDocument.songAttributes.title = newTitle`. I just don't know if this is the best practice and why it doesn't work without the override?

Isn't a derived property any property that needs to "do work"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to defined getter but not setter. You need to define setter as well.

```
//Getter
- (NSString *)title;
{
    return self.songDocument.songAttributes.title;
}

//Setter
- (void)setTitle:(NSString *)title;
{
    self.songDocument.songAttributes.title = title;
}
```

Comment: `self.songViewController.songWrapper.title = titleTextField.text;` calls the setter which is not defined.